# How to find the JavaScript that hangs the browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a webpage that hangs due to some of its javascript. I don't have access to the source code for this webpage.
Is there anyway that I can find the javascript that is causing the problem using chrome/IE dev tools?

Comment: you always have access to the source code of a webpage. right-click, view page source.

Comment: Both chrome and IE come with a javascript profiler that will show time usage in each sections of code, maybe that will show you what method/section of code is consuming the majority of the time.

Comment: alternatively, you can set a breakpoint at the beginning of the javascript and step over each line, waiting for it to hang. see: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging

Answer (score 3):

If you can open the webpage you have it's source code. In the worst case scenario the code is minified/obfuscated so it could be unreadable.

Using chrome you could check the profiles tab and start colllecting javascript cpu profile. After that you need to analyse where the execution time is spent.

[image: Profiles]

[image: Analysis]

Comment: I never considered the profile tool, and it has given me great insight to my issues. Thanks!